# Working with expression in R

Tags: r, expression

I'm a little new working with R, and I need create a expression like this.

```
myexpression = y ~ functionA(a=x[1],b=x$val,c=1,d=2)
```

It is not the problem. The problem is that I can not separate the attributes of function, so I'm doing it with this, `myexpression[[3]]`, and return `functionA(a=x[1],b=x$val,c=1,d=2)`, if I do it again `myexpression[[3]][[1]]`, this return `functionA`, but if I try to capture the attributes of the function only return the value of the attribute and I need also the key `myexpression[[3]][[2]]` return `x[1]` and I need `a=x[1]`.

Somebody may be know what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: I can't imagine that this is actually your problem. Perhaps you're a little far down the rabbit hole of solving your current issue. What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cat(
  names(myexpression[[3]])[[2]], "=",   # this retrieves the "a", plus adds and equal sign
  deparse(myexpression[[3]][[2]]),      # this retrievs `x[1]`, and makes it suitable for printing
  sep=""
)
```

produces (on the screen):

```
a=x[1]
```

You need to go to the `names` attribute.  Also, in order for `x[1]` to show up as you want it in this whole thing you need to deparse it.

Are you trying to evaluate this, or is this purely for display purposes?